# Home Network set-up question

Tags: internet

I'm a DIY'er and just had high speed fiber installed by Cox and decided to hardwire my entire house.

My wife works from home and has a separate Meraki router that she is required to plug into. She works out of two locations in our house and needs two ports ( *1 for VOIP and 1 for internet...she can't get internet through VOIP phone* ).

My home router will be plugged into a netgear 24 port switch.

My question is Can I take internet from my switch and plug into her Meraki and then allocate 2 ports on my patch panel that she can toggle between if she decides to move to the other location in our home??

I hope this make sense.

Side note: Both routers will sit on a Pyle shelf that will be installed

[image: network set up]

Comment: For your wife's two working locations, you will have two port connections, one for the VOIP and the other one for internet?  You are not concerned about other locations that your wife might to work in?  If this is the case, you can wire the patch panel and no toggle is required.  Just plug into the outlets in any of the two rooms.

Comment: As an aside, props for having a punch board and rack. Very nice for a home network.

Comment: Thank for the reply...She has two separate areas that she will be working from, each with two ports to plug into. I was thinking similarly to the comment below of going from her router by creating two keystone jacks in my patch panel that are just dedicated to her and then I/she can toggle the ethernet cords between the two location on the patch panel??  I wasn't sure if that is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier solution would be to just patch your wife's internet into a patch bay and then wire that patch to her router. You probably don't want to plug your entire internet into that router because that router likely uses a VPN to connect into her work network.

If you go internet -> home router -> Meraki router -> devices then everything that any of your devices does or searches would be visible to your wife's work.

I would suggest doing something like:

1. Internet
2. Home Router
3. Switch (or the extra port on your home router if you have one)

   1. Wifes Router -> Wife's devices
   2. Other Devices

Comment: As long as only his wife's devices are plugged into the Meraki router, and his personal devices are plugged into the home router, only traffic from her devices would pass the work VPN.

Comment: Thank you...I really like this idea. I just want to confirm that I can go from the switch to her router without issue??